# Android/Java File.mkdirs() in external storage not working

Tags: java, android, linux, android-sdcard

First off, I want to specify that I do have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

specified in my manifest, and I do check Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.

The really strange thing about this, in my opinion, is that it returns true, but it doesn't actually create the directories.

```
public static void downloadFiles(ArrayList<FileList> list) {

    for (FileList file: list) {
        try {
            // This will be the download directory
            File download = new File(downloadDirPatch.getCanonicalPath(), file.getPath());

            // downloadDirPatch is defined as follows in a different class:
            //
            // private static String updateDir = "CognitionUpdate";
            // private static File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // final public static File downloadDir = new File(sdcard, updateDir);
            // final public static File downloadDirPatch = new File(downloadDir, "patch");
            // final public static File downloadDirFile = new File(downloadDir, "file");

            if (DEV_MODE)
                Log.i(TAG, "Download file: " + download.getCanonicalPath());

            // Check if the directory already exists or not
            if (!download.exists())
                // The directory doesn't exist, so attempt to create it
                if (download.mkdirs()) {
                    // Directory created successfully
                    Download.download(new URL(file.getUrl() + file.getPatch()), file.getPath(), file.getName(), true);
                } else {
                    throw new ExternalStorageSetupFailedException("Download sub-directories could not be created");
                }
            else {
                // Directory already exists
                Download.download(new URL(file.getUrl() + file.getPatch()), file.getPath(), file.getName(), true);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExternalStorageSetupFailedException essfe) {
            essfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

"if (download.mkdirs())" returns true, but when the app goes to actually download the file it throws a

```
FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

exception, and when I check for the directory afterwards on my phone, it doesn't exist.

Earlier in the program, the app sets up the parent download directory, and that all works fine using File.mkdir(), but File.mkdirs() doesn't seem to be working properly for me.

Comment: What was the solution... I am having a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not give much detail about the `FileNotFoundException`. Check the path that triggers this. Forget what you *think* the path is, log it or run it through the debugger to see what it really is.

As per the directories not created correctly, verify (with your eyes) that the path is really what you *think* it is. I see you are already logging `download.getCanonicalPath`, do check in your logs what it really is.

Finally, is `Download.download` really saving stuff where you *think* it does? Before you call it you are preparing and verifying a directory using `download`, but then you are not using `download` when you call `Download.download`, so it's impossible to tell.

Btw, don't repeat yourself, you can rewrite without repeating the `Download.download` line:

```
        if (!download.exists())
            if (!download.mkdirs()) {
                throw new ExternalStorageSetupFailedException("Download sub-directories could not be created");
            }
        }
        Download.download(new URL(file.getUrl() + file.getPatch()), file.getPath(), file.getName(), true);
```

Comment: The path is correct, I have already checked it. And Download.download is really saving it where I think it is. The path is "/storage/emulated/0/CognitionUpdate/patch/path/of/this" and Download.download tries to save it to "/storage/emulated/0/CognitionUpdate/patch/path/of/this/this.patch". Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to do that too.

Comment: Also, the exception in full is:
`W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/CognitionUpdate/patch/path/of/this/this.patch: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Hmmm... And after `.mkdirs()` is successful, does `.exists()` and `.isDirectory()` return true also?

Comment: Yes, they both do. At this point I am just going to write my own mkdirs() method, because I can't possibly see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: My program logic was backwards, so the issue had nothing to do with any of this or File.mkdirs(). Moved one line of code and it all worked. Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: What was it I am running under a similar problem

Comment: Same here.  Would love to know what was "backwards" about it.